# Get latitude and longitude on android

Tags: android

I need to add a method to capture the latitude and longitude that I use to show it, I am only interested in obtaining the two values ​​when a button is pressed to show it and then I am no longer interested in moving. Thanks in advance. This form turned out to me but sometimes it returns to me null I don't know why?

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(this.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation (locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));

double latitudActual =  location.getLatitude();
double longitudActual = location.getLongitude();
```

Comment: Please provide the error message. Dont post it on comment edit your question

Comment: Please research similar questions first and in your question reference any question you are using which causes confusion: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+location+null

Answer (score 0):

You are using getlastknowLocation which might be null
Try using location listener as stated here
[How do I get the current GPS location programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android)